# Clipping Composition Animation?

Tags: uwp, windows-composition-api

I have this problem I have an Control I want to animate by using Composition API offset extension method to animate movement by the distance of its width to the right. So far so good.

But I also want all of it that slides out of its original boundary to be clipped. So it essentially slides right and disappears. How do I accomplish this? I have a vague notion I might need to use InsetClip but I'm not sure how to combine it with the animation...

Comment: Could you share the code that you have done?

Comment: Can you show a image about the effect that you  want to have?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I'm stupid. I can just put a Clip on an outer border and do the animation as usual :P